# Using axios to send JS variables to PHP mpdf file

Tags: javascript, php, mpdf

I'm attempting to use axios to send some variables to a PHP file which uses mpdf to generate a PDF using some of the data displayed on the page. My axios.get looks something like this:

```
axios.get('generatepdf.php', {
    params: {
        a: jsVariable1,
        b: jsVariable2,
        c: jsVariable3,
        d: jsVariable4,
        e: jsVariable5,
        f: jsVariable6
    }
});
```

And then in my PHP file it looks like this:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// grab variables from JS
$a= $_GET['a'];
$b= $_GET['b'];
$c= $_GET['c'];
$d= $_GET['d'];
$e= $_GET['e'];
$f= $_GET['f'];

// create new PDF instance
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();


$data = '';

$data .= '<strong>a:</strong> ' . $a . '<br>';
$data .= '<strong>b:</strong> ' . $b . '<br>';
$data .= '<strong>c:</strong> ' . $c . '<br>';
$data .= '<strong>d:</strong> ' . $d . '<br>';
$data .= '<strong>e:</strong> ' . $e . '<br>';
$data .= '<strong>f:</strong> ' . $f . '<br>';

// write PDF
$mpdf->WriteHTML($data);

// output to browser
$mpdf->Output('file.pdf', 'D');

exit;
?>
```

I'm using an onclick event in the HTML to the JavaScript. I have gotten this to work using Vue before but I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The goal here is to generate the PDF with the data from my JavaScript.

Comment: Welcome to SO! On glance, this looks like it should work. What's the error or issue you're running into with this code? Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, for resurrecting such an old thread, but this was for my first Vue.js and PHP project and I was trying to figure out how to get things to work. I am since long finished with it.

I'm not sure I supplied enough information to fully allow others to come up with a solution (I'm using Vue.js with data members), but my jsVariables were class members rather than variables. The problem was that I forgot the `this` keyword.

```
params: {
    a: this.classMember1,
    b: this.classMember2,
    c: this.classMember3,
    d: this.classMember4,
    e: this.classMember5,
    f: this.classMember6
}
```

Very important to specify `this` as it relates to data members of a class and not non-class variables.